# Grab all of a User's Active Posts

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

My instance method of `active_posts` is not working on my `User` model.

I am grabbing a `user` record, then for that record I need to join the `blogs` and `posts` table, and then filter by the post's `active` attribute in order to return only the active `posts` for that `user`.

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :blogs
  has_many :posts, through: :blogs

  def active_posts
    joins(blogs: :posts).merge(Post.active).distinct
  end
end

class Blog < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :posts
end

class Post < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :blog
  belongs_to :user, through: :blog

  scope :active, -> {where(active: true}
end
```

I run the following:

```
User.first.active_posts
```

And here is the error:

> NoMethodError
>   Undefined method 'joins' on the user record

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just realized my error.

Just call `posts.active` within the `active_posts` method.

```
def active_posts
  posts.active
end
```

`joins` is used for a collection.  So you would use `joins` on a class method in your model, not within an instance method.  Simple error.

Comment: `joins` is a class method - you were calling it from an instance.